# What am I? (tough riddle must give an explanation)

Tags: riddle, wordplay

I am always there but never here

I live to love but hate to live

I feed off passion but am always starving

I long for pain but hate its coming

I'm ever seeking but never finding

I wait and wait but it’s always too late

I am finite

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Jealousy

Explanation:

I am always there but never here

> You're never jealous of yourself, only of others and other things

I live to love but hate to live

> Jealousy lives in love - if you love it and don't have it you're probably jealous of it. We all hate being jealous. It sucks to be jealous. Thus, when you are jealous of something (When jealousy lives), you hate it.

Edit:

> Jealousy lives TO love; you're jealous of it probably because you love it - if we described jealousy as a person, the point of jealousy's life would be to love something. However, don't forget that Ms.J hates herself and her life - being jealous all the time is stressful, depressing, and just crappy. She "hates to live".

I feed off passion but am always starving

> Jealousy is an emotion (feeds off passion since you are usually jealous of what you have a passion for, or something you like, etc). Always starving because you don't have what you're seeking. For example, if you don't have x, it can be worded as "you've been starved of x"

I long for pain but hate its coming

> Jealousy causes pain, but (almost) everyone hates pain.

I'm ever seeking but never finding

> Jealousy only exists as long as there is something to be jealous of - when you finally get it, you're not looking for it anymore, and as such, you cannot "find" it.

I wait and wait but it’s always too late

> If you're jealous, it's already too late. You could've gone out and bought x or done y, but at the end of the day you waited too long and you're sitting there, watching. Jealously. Waiting. But it was too late, you missed your chance.

I am finite

> When you finally get what you want, even if you were jealous of it before, you stop being jealous of it; therefore, finite - it ends.

Comment: Bravo! but could you rewrite your explanation of "live to love, but hate to live". i think you misread it as "live in love, but hate to live".  I'm interested to see what you come up with.

Comment: bleeeeeegh i spent a good hour at work writing that one up lol - do you mean to say that jealousy is the wrong answer, or that if i could justify that line it would be ok?

Comment: just asking to justify that line. jealousy is correct. and your explanations are spot on except for that one

Comment: @adamkim Did I get it?